# Was US Postmaster General Louis DeJoy "approved by both parties"? To what extent can the board's voting be established as bipartisan?

Tags: united-states, parties, political-appointments, postal-service

In the video [Trump says he would support investigation into postmaster general](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3dAoD8BPaQ) the US President emphasizes that the current [US Postmaster General](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Postmaster_General) namely [Louis DeJoy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_DeJoy) was "appointed by a bipartisan commission".

I've done my best to transcribe the parts of the president's spoken answer to a question about recent news and concerns where the "bipartisan-ness" of DeJoy's appointment is emphasized:

After `00:14`:

> He’s very respected man, he was approved, uh... very much uh... by both parties I guess, it was sort of an approval that took place by both parties.

After `00:39`:

> Again it was a uh... bipartisan commission, postmaster general’s appointed by a bipartisan commission...

The Wikipedia article states that it is the [Board of Governors of the United States Postal Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Board_of_Governors_of_the_United_States_Postal_Service) that makes the appointment and this article states:

> The Board of Governors of the United States Postal Service is the governing body of the United States Postal Service (USPS). The board oversees the activities of the Postal Service, while the postmaster general actively manages its day-to-day operations.
>
> The board directs "the exercise of the power" of the Postal Service, controls its expenditures and reviews its practices and policies. It consists of 11 members, 6 are requisite to achieve an ordinary quorum. Of the 11 board members, 9 are the presidentially-appointed governors, 1 is the postmaster general, and 1 is the deputy postmaster general. The 9 governors elect the postmaster general, the chairman of the board as well as the USPS inspector general; the governors and the postmaster general elect the deputy postmaster general. No more than five governors may be adherents of the same political party. The board also has the power to remove all of these officers.
>
> The Board of Governors is comparable with the board of directors of most private corporations.

There was a resignation from the board by "David Williams, a former USPS inspector general and former vice chairman of the service’s board of governors" (quoted from LATimes article linked below) just days before DeJoy's appointment was approved.

**Question:** How bipartisan was the *approval* of DeJoy. Is there (just for example) an enumeration of each board member's name, the vote that they cast, and their party adherence that would demonstrate that the US president's claim that DeJoy was "approved by both parties" has a basis in facts?

Does admission to the board require a declaration of party adherence, or are some members "undeclared"?

---

Additional reading:

- Los Angeles Times: [Column: DeJoy’s appointment as postmaster general looks even more dishonest than you thought](https://www.latimes.com/business/story/2020-08-21/dejoy-appointment-postmaster-dishonest)
- USPS official site: [Board of Governors Announces Selection of Louis DeJoy to Serve as Nation’s 75th Postmaster General](https://about.usps.com/newsroom/national-releases/2020/0506-bog-announces-selection-of-louis-dejoy-to-serve-as-nations-75th-postmaster-general.htm)
- NBC News: [Mnuchin's role in postmaster's appointment becomes target](https://www.nbcnews.com/politics/politics-news/mnuchin-s-role-postmaster-s-appointment-becomes-target-n1237553)
- [What happens if not all ballots cast by mail arrive in time to be counted for the November elections?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/56348/16047) posts contain additional relevant content and sources
- [Does the US postmaster have the power to decide by themselves to whom to award a $6.5 billion contract?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/70810/16047)

Comment: While the US Post Office had traditionally been considered to be apolitical, this question is about the political aspects of the voting to approve Louis DeJoy and the *politicization* of heretofore apolitical processes by the politician Donald Trump and by their political appointees (in this case Treasury Secretary Steven Mnuchin).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by a bi-partisan commission you mean one that has 4 republicans (5 if you count DeJoy) and 2 (1 of which joined the commission after DeJoy was picked) Democrats all of whom were appointed by Trump? Even if the Democrats on the board of governors wanted to vote against him would it matter?

It should also be noted that both Democrats have been appointed in the last year and both have short terms. One is from August 2019 to December 2020 and the other is from June 2020 to December 2022. Something to note is there is a restriction of 5 members from the same party which the Republican party is currently at.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Board_of_Governors_of_the_United_States_Postal_Service#Current_members

> Louis DeJoy, Postmaster General, Republican, June 15, 2020, No term limit
> Robert M. Duncan, Governor, Chairman, Republican, August 2018, December 8, 2025
> Roman Martinez IV, Governor, Republican, August 1, 2019,December 8, 2024
> John McLeod Barger, Governor, Republican, August 1, 2019, December 8, 2021
> William D. Zollars, Governor, Republican, June 18, 2020, December 8, 2022
> Donald L. Moak, Governor, Democratic, June 18, 2020 December 8, 2022
> Ron A. Bloom, Governor, Democratic, August 20, 2019, December 8, 2020

Comment: The composition of the commission during the selection of DeJoy and the commission's role in that selection are both probably required in the text to make this a good answer rather than with raw wikipedia link. Why those new Democrat appointees have short terms is probably an interesting second question.

Comment: Similar problem in [this answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/56946/16047) in that the answer is in the link, not in your post. In Stack Exchange this is called a link-only answer and this is quite discouraged. if the link breaks, the answer loses all value and the question becomes unanswered. This can be easily addressed by quoting the specific bit of information directly in your post that supports your claims.

Comment: It might be worth noting in the answer that there should be 9 governors appointed by the US President of which only 5 can be from the same party.  Leaving positions unfilled seems like exploiting a loophole.

Comment: Any thoughts on " Is there... an enumeration of each board member's name, the vote that they cast, and their party adherence that would demonstrate that the US president's claim that DeJoy was "approved by both parties" has a basis in facts?